# Pass dynamic params to cell renderer in parent component (ag grid)

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

How to pass dynamic params based on cell params?
Like here when we adding class based on cell params

```
cellClassRules: {
   'error-border': (params: any) => {
      return params.error;
    },
},
```

I want to do the same with cellRendererParams but it not working:

```
cellRendererParams: {
  someProp: (params: any) => {
    return ...;
  },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Say I have a custom cell renderer.  It has a property called myProp that I want to set:

```
export class MyCellRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {

  params: any;
  myProp = true;
}
```

In the component I want to use it I have to add it to the list of components:

```
<ag-grid [components]="components" >

components = {
    myCellRenderer: MyCellRendererComponent
  };
```

Then when I set up my columns I can specify the cell renderer and set the myProp property like this:

```
{
  field: 'myField',
  width: 150,
  cellRenderer: 'myCellRenderer',
  cellRendererParams: {
    myProp: (params) => {
      console.log(params.data.myPropValue); // <-- Can you try this?
      return params.data.myPropValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Is your custom component definitely being used?  Can you put a console.log when you are setting your custom property?

Let me know how you get on